# How do I add two variables of different classes?

Tags: python

I am currently making a class called fractions and need to define a function that adds integers to these fractions. The code I wrote gives the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
Breuk(1,3) + 1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Breuk' and 'int'

```
import math

class Breuk:
    def __init__(self, teller=1, noemer=1):
        self.teller = int(teller)
        self.noemer = int(noemer)
        while math.gcd(self.teller, self.noemer) != int(1):
            factor = math.gcd(self.teller, self.noemer)
            self.teller = int(self.teller / factor)
            self.noemer = int(self.noemer / factor)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.teller) + '/' + str(self.noemer)
    
    def __add__(self,other):
        if type(other) == int:
            other = Breuk(other, 1)
        elif type(self) == int:
            self.teller = self
            self.noemer = 1
        r = Breuk()
        r.teller = self.noemer*other.teller + self.teller*other.noemer
        r.noemer = self.noemer*other.noemer
        
        while math.gcd(r.teller, r.noemer) != 1:
            factor = int(math.gcd(r.teller, r.noemer))
            r.teller = int(r.teller / factor)
            r.noemer = int(r.noemer / factor)
        return r
```

Comment: Use `isinstance(other, int)` instead of `type(other) == int`

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement the dunder ‘radd’ method.

Comment: Following up with @quamrana, you should check out the documentation for [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) :)

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't ran into this problem while testing the code so I thought there was nothing wrong, but yeah you were right.
Turns out you just need to add this bit of code:

```
def __radd__(self,other):
    if isinstance(other, int):
        other = Breuk(other, 1)
    elif type(self) == int:
        self.teller = self
        self.noemer = 1
    r = Breuk()
    r.teller = self.noemer*other.teller + self.teller*other.noemer
    r.noemer = self.noemer*other.noemer
    
    while math.gcd(r.teller, r.noemer) != 1:
        factor = int(math.gcd(r.teller, r.noemer))
        r.teller = int(r.teller / factor)
        r.noemer = int(r.noemer / factor)
    return r
```

Calling 5.**add**(Beurk(5, 3)) will fail and it will then call Beurk(5, 3).**radd**(5) wich will work

Answer (score -1):

It works for me but if it doesn't for you, try this:

```
if isinstance(other, int):
    other = Breuk(other, 1)
```

Comment: Try adding something like: `5 + Breuk(3,5)` It will return the exact error asked in the question.